# Save function not working in Eloquent,

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**Code that is executed when I like a post**

```
   // auth()->id() is the id of the user that liked the post
   $post->post_likes()->associate(auth()->id());
   $post->save();
```

**Error that occurs after the code runs**

Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate does not exist.

-

**Post Model**

```
class Post extends Model
{

    public function post_likes()
    {            
        return $this->hasMany(PostLike::Class);
    }

}
```

**Update**

I got the like to work by doing this.

```
$post_like =  PostLike::create([
     'post_id' => $post->id,
     'user_id' => auth()->id()
]);

$post->post_likes()->save($post_like);
```

Now I am having trouble removing the like. The code below gets executed when I dislike a post. The error that occurs is:

Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::dissociate does not exist.

```
$post->post_likes->dissociate();

$post->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the  [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) `attach` and `detach` functions are for Many to Many relationships. Use `save` for **One To Many** relationships

Comment: I'm getting an error. "Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate does not exist".

Comment: Have you pre define 'use Auth'?

Answer (score 0):

oneToMany you should use associate and dissociate.

ManyToMany you should use attach and detach.

**so all you need is to change associate to attach and that's it.**

and after you use **the both** you need to **save**.

check the documentation [OneToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) & [ManyToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships).